# Can I Read CRC and ACK bits using SocketCAN?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, socketcan

I'm looking for a way to send messages from one Raspberry Pi via PiCan2 to another and receive back to read CRC and ACK bits. I searched the documentation but couldn't find such an option, could I have missed something?

Answer (score 0):

You do not deal directly with **CRC** and **ACK**, but you can be notified when such events happen. All relevant info can be found in [Linux SocketCAN documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/can.html).

If you want implementation details, at [this link](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,39858.msg403874.html#msg403874) you can find my **hlcanerrdump** tool which can parse and show all errors on CAN bus, and **hlcanerrsim** tool for simulating all kinds of CAN bus errors. Study the source code and you will understand how to achieve what you want.